# HERE Maps 'Avoid TollRoad' supported regions

Tags: maps, here-api, heremaps, here-maps-rest

I want to know if the **Avoid=TollRoad** parameter is supported across all regions/countries. Is there any documentation where I might be able to see what regions are supported? Asking for a web app. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Assuming this is for Car/Scooter Routing) Avoid=TollRoad parameter is associated with routing services and the region dependencies are similar to it. You can find the list of navigable countries at https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/topics/coverage/navigable-countries.html.

If you are looking for the coverage for different vehicle types, please refer the following.

EV Routing - https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/topics/coverage/ev-routing.html

Truck Routing - https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/topics/coverage/truck-routing.html

/MS